# the type or namespace name "RigidBody2D" could not be found

Tags: c#, unity3d

Решил сделать 2д платформер и учусь по видосам с примерами. Обратил внимание что синтаксис скрипта c# даже не подсвечивается а потом начал получать ошибку: The type or namespace name 'RigidBody2D' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? Хотя вроде написал все правильно и должно работать(думаю может не хватает каких нибудь библиотек?)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private int lives = 3;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce = 5f;

    private RigidBody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentinChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horzintal"))
            Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image: пример отсутствия синтаксиса]

Comment: **Rigidbody2D**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри В чём конкретно ошибка объяснить подробно не смогу, но это связано с тем, что ты не выбрал как открывать, точнее чем открывать скрипты. Вот как решить проблему:

В общём Заходишь в свой проект в Unity, в верху нажимаешь на Edit -> Preferences... .
Там выбираешь External Tools и в External Script Editor выбираешь VS 2019

Comment: Проблема исчезла. Я бы врятли догадался до этого. Спасибо!